# How to access Queue for MQ7?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

```
        qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);            
        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
               | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT |  MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;        

       *queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);* //Here i need to change it for MQ7, as for Mq7 their is no Queue Manager Name.

        System.out.println("Successfully registered");
```

Hi all,

I need to monitor the queue for `IBM MQ7`.. Currently we did for `MQ6`, but for `MQ7` their no Queue Manager name and 'm stuck with this. Can anyone help me

Comment: Where did you get this info, that you don't need QM name in MQ7 API?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? Are you getting any exception? Provide some more details.

Comment: i want to monitor a queue.. my colleagues told tat they hv a tool wrkng for MQ6 where ther z Queuemanager ... they want me to wrk thz tool for MQ7 whr thr z no Queue manager.. when i analyzed it thr was a line "*queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);* " here thz wrkd bcoz of Queue Manager.. but i want it to work without queue manager. kindly help me.

Comment: hi NITGEEK.. u wr rite. Thr z queue manager available but its optional. so they people who are creating the queue will not provide the queue manager details since its optional. But without queue manager name i wont be able to do thz "queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions); ".. Kindly help me..

Comment: @AlexMichaelRaj: Please use plain English when writing in SO. short forms does not help and many times lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have understood your question:

First be clear that you can not connect to something that does not exist whether it is a server or anything. To connect an object that object must exist.

The same case applies to MQ also. To connect to a queue manager, that queue manager must be existing and running.

Coming to the snippet you mention: MQ Java API does not have a `MQQueueManager` constructor that does `not` take a queue manager name parameter. So queue manager name parameter is mandatory and not optional. But you can pass "" (blank) as the name of the queue manager to MQQueueManager constructor. In such a case  the application will connect to a queue manager based on the host, port  and channel parameters. So you must pass at least host, port and channel parameters.

Hope I have answered your question.

**EDIT** Sample Code

```
    // Create a connection to the QueueManager
    qManager = "";    
    System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager: " + qManager);
    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

    // Change the host name to your host name. Leave it as it is if 
    // queue manager is on the same machine
    props.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost"); 
    props.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
    props.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");

    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);
```

Comment: ..thanks for the reply.. i tried with "" as you said but not able to do it. Can you give an example. Actually your idea is good but i dont know to implement it properly

Comment: i have posted the code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681980/program-to-create-a-connection-and-access-ibm-mq-7) . The first program is the code I am using.

Comment: this is the error i get : MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.

Comment: thanks for the update.. i tried but still getting the same error "com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'". Anyhow tomorrow i will check it again and let you know. Thanks for your help

Comment: You will need post your entire program for me comment.

Comment: the code you asked is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681980/program-to-create-a-connection-and-access-ibm-mq-7) . I did changes only for the first program

Comment: its pointing the error on the line 'qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);'

Comment: i am trying to connect it with MQ7 server.

Comment: Hi.. its working with the other code which you gave me 

'environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,QUEUE_CONTEXT);
            environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,QUEUE_URL);

            ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);    
            connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(MYCF_LOOKUP_NAME);'

Comment: Even the sample code I posted above should also work. If you have a queue manager running the specified host(localhost in the sample) and listening at the specified port (1414 in the sample).

Comment: sorry.. it didn't work. Actually I added a catch block to handle the exception and i dint see it properly. 'm getting the exception as 
avax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'gihgateway-dev.dnb.com:'
Inner exception(s):
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'gihgateway-dev.dnb.com(1434)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9205: 
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9205: 
Plz help me :( :(

Comment: Buddy.. you are great @Shashi It worked with MQ-6.. because of firewall issue.. its rejecting the connection and tats the reason I am getting this error.. will let you know in two days.

Comment: hi.. i tried with MQ 7 .. its connecting but throwing error when trying to send the second message.. here is the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290053/java-program-mq-7-connection-issue)

Comment: I can't see any link, so don't know what the error is. My guess is that you are trying to use the same MQMessage object (which is created before sending first message) when sending second message also. Suggest you to create a new MQMessage object every time when sending message.

Comment: this is the link --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290053/java-program-mq-7-connection-issue  
K then i will try as you said

Comment: hi.. now the code is messages are being sent but i can confirm only on Monday, as i dont have the rights to check. Actually I disabled the method 
'public long getQueueCount() throws Exception{
            return queue.getCurrentDepth();
        }'
this is used to find the queue depth i.e. queue count for the graph i am creating.. Can you suggest any other ways..?

Comment: hi.. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300126/need-to-access-the-queue-depth-of-mq-7