# Java program MQ 7 connection issue

Tags: java, connection, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect to the MQ7 Server below is the code :

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

        // Change the host name to your host name. Leave it as it is if 
        // queue manager is on the same machine
        props.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, serverConfig.server); 
        props.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, serverConfig.port);
        props.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, serverConfig.sChannel);

        qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);
        System.out.println("Queue Manager : "+qMgr+" null");

        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
                | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT |  MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;

        queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

        System.out.println("Successfully registered");

        //creating msg
        message = new MQMessage();
```

it's getting connected but after sending one message its throwing a error

```
" MQJE001: Completion Code '1', Reason '2068'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '1', Reason '2068'.
strngError: No valid counters.
strngError: No valid counters.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedObject.inquire(MQManagedObject.java:269)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedObject.getInt(MQManagedObject.java:479)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueue.getCurrentDepth(MQQueue.java:995)
    at middlewarex.IBMmq.getQueueCount(IBMmq.java:227)
    at middlewarex.ThreadScenario.run(ThreadScenario.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

pointing on the line

```
" public long getQueueCount() throws Exception{
            return queue.getCurrentDepth();
        } "
```

Kindly Help me

Comment: i get this error when i try to send the second message.. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Did you look up Reason Code 2068 in the manual?  Because if you did, you would have seen that using option MQOO_INQUIRE is invalid.

Secondly, why are you opening the queue for BOTH putting and getting messages?  This is a VERY bad practice.  You say you are sending (putting) a message to a queue, therefore, you should be opening the queue for output only.

Comment: I looked in the error codes.. but dint understand.. 
can you be more specific.. on the line you are telling

Comment: hi.. now i disabled the method 
' public long getQueueCount() throws Exception{
            return queue.getCurrentDepth();
        } '
and its working fine but i need to check in the server whether the messages are received or not and that i can confirm only on Monday. Basically i am using this method to get the queue depth for creating a graph. can you suggest any other way of finding queue depth.

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300126/need-to-access-the-queue-depth-of-mq-7)

Answer (score 0):

Due to firewall I was facing the exception when sending the message. Please try telnet and check whether the firewall is blocking you from accessing the machine.