# Need to Access the Queue depth of MQ 7

Tags: java, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

My Below is the code works good with MQ6 but for MQ7 its giving exception

```
'package javaapplication1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
 import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
    import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
    import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
    import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;
class Connectivity 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MQException
    {
       String qManager="";
       int port_num=0;
    int openOptions =  CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;

    MQEnvironment.hostname = "Host_name";
    MQEnvironment.port = port_num;
    MQEnvironment.channel = "Chn_name";
    System.out.println("Connecting to queue manager: " + qManager);
            Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

            // Change the host name to your host name. Leave it as it is if 
            // queue manager is on the same machine
            props.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "Host_name"); 
            props.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port_num);
            props.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "Chn_Name");

            MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);
    //MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("SW1_QM");

    MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("Q_Name",   openOptions);

    System.out.println("E_RETRY size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());
    destQueue.close();
    qMgr.disconnect();
    }


}'
```

I get exception on the line

'System.out.println("E_RETRY size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());'

and the exception message is

```
'MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedObject.inquire(MQManagedObject.java:257)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedObject.getInt(MQManagedObject.java:428)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueue.getCurrentDepth(MQQueue.java:1478)
    at javaapplication1.Connectivity.main(Connectivity.java:36)
Java Result: 1'
```

Kindly help me..

Answer (score 2):

Your open option does not include `MQOO_INQUIRE` which is a must for getting queue depth. I expected a MQRC 2038 because MQOO_INQUIRE option was not specified.

Not sure why you are initializing MQEnvironment also and you are passing a properties hash table to MQQueueManager constructor.

Anyway here is the sample code that gets queue depth for a local queue.

```
public static void getQueueDepth()
{
            String qManager="QM1";
    int port_num=1414;
    int openOptions =  CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;

    try {
            Hashtable props = new Hashtable();

            props.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost"); 
            props.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port_num);
            props.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");

            MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);

            MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE",   openOptions);

            System.out.println("E_RETRY size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());
            destQueue.close();
            qMgr.disconnect();
    }catch(MQException mqe){
        System.out.println(mqe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shashi.. As u said .. i used like this -- int 'openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
               | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT |  MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;  '    it showed error on depth.. Okay then i will try on Monday and will reply to you. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I tried with your code its giving me the same exception.. 
After searching in the internet.. I Added few open_options
`int openOptions =  CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE+CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
            System.out.println("E_RETRY size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());`but still giving the same exception..
Error -- Code -- `MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068`

Comment: Actually Shashi.. the code is working fine with MQ6 i.e. finding the Queue Depth.. but its showing exception when i try to find for MQ 7..

Comment: I strongly recommend you to contact IBM support to resolve the issue. I am not seeing the problem you are facing. There seems to be something different in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the properties of the queue are different between the v6 and v7 queue managers?  The [documentation for the error message](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc/fm12690_.htm&resultof=%222068%22%20) indicates this can occur with a cluster queue that resolves to a remote instance of the queue.

Have you verified that destQueue is in fact a valid queue?

Comment: hey.. i checked in that link and i added in the open_options in my program `int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE+CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE; ` but still pointing on the same line.. `System.out.println("E_RETRY size:" + destQueue.getCurrentDepth());`
error -- code -- 
`MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068 com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 1, Reason 2068 –`